# What's the difference between < and @ scope isolation in angularJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My Rails app has different organization with their profile page with their own inventory stats table.

Written below is the part of *app/views/organization/show.html.erb*

```
<div ng-app="cc-app" class="card-body overflow-hidden">
    //codes here
    <inventory-stats orgid="<%= @organization.id %>"> </inventory-stats>
    //codes here
</div>
```

I have made a directive to show inventory stats and pass orgid i.e Organization ID with scope isolation(one-way binding) to get organization's inventory stats. As far as I know I have two ways of defining scope object for one-way binding in *app/assets/javascripts/angular/directives/inventoryStats.directive.js* which are:

Either

```
scope: {
    orgid: '@'
    }
```

Or,

```
scope: {
    orgid: '<'
    }
```

But only @ seems to work. With @, $scope.orgid gives the values of Organization ID in directives scope. And if I pass orgid with < its undefined. I have read [directive's scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) and still don't know why < is not working.

My AngularJS:
*AngularJS v1.6.10*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        param1: '@',
        param2: '<'
      },
      template: '<div><pre>param1= {{param1|json}}</pre><pre>param2= {{param2|json}}</pre></div>'
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="scopeValue=[1,2,3]">
  <my-directive param1="string-value" param2="scopeValue"></my-directive>
</div>
```

`@` is used to pass interpolations as a **string** value only.

`<` is one way data binding from parent to child, you can pass what ever data value you want with it.

Comment: Exactly what i needed to understand this. Thank you so much!! One more question, does this mean that we can't pass rails variable with < scope isolation??

Comment: It is not relevant, server side vars should be passed somehow to js, you can do it with attribute assignment like you did.